# Random forest for binomial data

Tags: r, cross-validation, binomial-distribution, random-forest

I have data where the response is of the form (k,n) - k successes, n trials for a given subject.  The covariates are just some subject-specific predictors.  Is it possible to use randomForest for this?  I have thought about replicating the data so that for each subject we have n lines, k of which have the y-value '1' and n-k of which have the y-value '0' - is there an alternative?  This makes cross-validation pretty messy, because I want to be able to predict p=k/n for new subjects, and I think the cross-validation would have to be 'locked' so that each training set contains all the rows for a given subject, or none of them.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out and tell us how it goes? is "n" decided before hand for each exercise? maybe you can just predict k and introduce n as an independent variable. If you are interested in p=k/n why don't you just predict that?